# Import specified columns from CSV, by header name, and export to new file

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv, import-csv

I want to make a ps1 that takes all .csv in a folder, pulls out all values under 2 columns (identified by header), then spits out new .csv for each file with only these two columns.

I can make it work on individual files, below, but when I add a wildcard it says function doesn't work on multiple files. I have tried other methods but I don't have a formal CS background (so my "script" below might seem rudimentary); I get close but nothing is working so far.

```
$inputpath = 'C:/Users/AAA/AAA/AAA/AAA/'
$inputfile = 'BBB.csv'
$outputpath = $inputpath
$outputfile = $inputfile.basename + 'edited' + '.csv'

Import-Csv $inputpath$inputfile |
    select COLUMNtitle1, COLUMNtitle2 |
    Export-Csv -Path $outputpath$outputfile -NoTypeInformation

echo
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't using `Get-ChildItem` for `$inputfile` then there isn't a `basename` property. Also it's safer to use `Join-Path` when joining paths and better to avoid `+` to concatenate strings.

```
$inputfolder = 'C:\Users\AAA\AAA\AAA\AAA\'
Get-ChildItem $inputfolder -include *.csv | % {
    $outputpath = Join-Path $inputfolder "$($_.basename)edited.csv"
    Import-Csv $_.fullname | select COLUMNtitle1,COLUMNtitle2 | Export-Csv -Path $outputpath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Thanks BenH.  This helps a lot.

Two questions:
1: I had to change 
       $inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder
then it ran all the .csv in one go. This puts all results into one .csv output, which is fine, but j/w how I would write it to create a separate .csv corresponding to each input?

2. Also, the output .csv file is just named "edited.csv". $($inputobject.basename), I assume because there is more than one input file?

Comment: @physlexic answer edited to handle all of the files in a folder.